# Select monitor for indicator information - choose the 'most right' monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, notification, notify-osd

How would You set display notification to appear on the 'right/secondary' desktop

Currently no matter what I configure, it appears in the top-right corner of the left desktop :/

```
+---------------+---------------+
|            [X]|               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|               |            [X]|
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I did set:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.notify-osd
com.canonical.notify-osd gravity 1
com.canonical.notify-osd multihead-mode 'dont-focus-follow
```

Missing the setting for the 'display selection'

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, that's it. These are the only two options available.

[https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/notify-osd/trunk/view/head:/data/com.canonical.NotifyOSD.gschema.xml](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eindicator-applet-developers/notify-osd/trunk/view/head:/data/com.canonical.NotifyOSD.gschema.xml)